# Как изолировать работу одной библиотеки от другой?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно выйти из ситуации, когда в проекте одна из библиотек требует одну версию пакета, а код проекта написан на другой версии пакета.

Конкретный пример: В моём проекте код для работы с БД написан с использованием библиотеки SQLAlchemy 2.0, сейчас я пытаюсь подключить apache-airflow который у себя на борту использует SQLAlhemy 1.4.48. После установки airflow по умолчанию стояла версия 1.4.48, но с ней мой код не работает, но при попытке запустить DAG с версией 2.0 выходит ошибка:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'encoding' sent to create_engine(), using configuration SQLiteDialect_pysqlite/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

Пытаться что-то скорректировать в исходных файлах библиотеки я конечно же не стал, в связи с чем возник вопрос, а как совместить эти пакеты?

UPD: в [официальной документации Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html) есть упоминание об установке с ограничениями. настроенными библиотекой airflow, но как я не пытался проблема остаётся, интерпретатор видит только одну версию пакета

Comment: Напрямую - никак, танцы с бубном и venv точно потребуются. Если на скиле, то вот суперский ответ на твой вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308293/how-to-install-python-package-with-a-different-name-using-pip. К сожалению разрабы python не подумали о такой возможности. И из коробки нечего толкового не найти

Comment: Или ждать выхода новой версии airflow, или переходить на старый sqlalchemy, или отказываться от использования библиотеки